# How to get Image from SWTBotTreeItem?

Tags: eclipse, ui-automation, swtbot

So I have an Eclipse based application, that I need to write automated UI test for. The solution is, obviously, SWTBot. 
There is a `TreeItem` with an `Image`, that can (in the application code) be accessed with `item.getImage()`. 
How do I access the image from SWTBot if I have the correct `SWTBotTreeItem`? I have looked through the API docs and found nothing useful, googling also did not yield any relevant results.